# Erro ao executar consulta Sql Server com jtds

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estou como uma situação estranha, meu código funciona perfeitamente no meu ambiente.  No tablet do cliente não funciona...  A única diferença é que o meu tablet está com a opção de desenvolvedor habilitada.  Criei a aplicação para versão 3, o tablet do cliente está com a versão 4.0.3.  Segue o código que quando altero ocorre erro: Funciona nos dois ambientes

```
 Button btnTestaConexao = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnTestarConexao);
 btnTestaConexao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ConsultaProduto produto = new ConsultaProduto();
        Boolean conexaoOk = produto.testaConexao(new ParametroConexao(edtBanco.getText().toString(), edtIp.getText().toString(), edtUsuario.getText().toString(), edtSenha.getText().toString(), edtInstancia.getText().toString()), (ConsultaPrecoActivity) getActivity());
        if (conexaoOk) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Conexão estabelecida com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Falha na conexão", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
 });
```

Ao inserir o código abaixo dentro do `if(conexãoOk)` só da erro no cliente:

```
 Produto _produto = produto.consultaProdutoEstoque("012162043052", getActivity());
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "executou consulta...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 if (_produto != null) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Produto: " + _produto.getDescricao(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Qual é o erro? Coloque o erro que aparece no logcat.

Comment: Jorge, obrigado por responder.  No meu ambiente não da erro e no cliente a aplicação simplesmente aborta.  Estou iniciando no Android, será que tenho algum comando que só funciona quando a opção de desenvolvedor está habilitada?

Comment: Isso não me parece que aconteça. Deve ser outra coisa...

Comment: Quase de certeza que o `produto` deve estar null. Ou isso ou outra variável.

Comment: Verifica se tens o mesmo conteúdo na base de dados.

Comment: Sem ter o log de erro fica complicado saber o que se passa...

Comment: Realmente, concordo com você, sem o log fica difícil.  Os dados estão ok, o produto existe.  O que é estranho que sem a consulta, executando somente o teste de conexão funciona, quando coloco a consulta nem o teste de conexão é executado.  Digo isso porque incluí um Toast na primeira linha do método do clique e não está exibindo a mensagem.

Comment: Então o problema tem de estar nessas linhas.

Comment: Me parece que está sendo feita alguma verificação antes de executar o código em si, tipo um parse do código.  Tem lógica o que falei?

Comment: Faz um if(produto!=null)  e mete essas linhas dentro.

Comment: Vou fazer esse teste, retorno com o resultado.  Obrigado.

Comment: Jorge, incluí todo código no if que você sugeriu.  Ao clicar no botão, se consigo conectar, o tablet exibi a mensagem que aplicação parou e aborta, nem exibe um toast que incluí na primeira linha do método.  Caso ocorra erro na conexão a aplicação informa corretamente a falha de conexão.  Deve ser algum detalhe que não estou conseguindo identificar.

Comment: Acho que estou no caminho, incluí um try..catch...  Vou fazer mais alguns testes e retorno.

Comment: Boa sorte amigo :)

Comment: Jorge, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda.  O problema estava na sintaxe da query, tinha uma coluna no select com IIF(PRO_VALOR> 0,PRO_VALOR,PRE_PRECO2) as preco, após substituir por 0 (zero) funcionou.  Estou usando o drive jtds para acessar o sql server, sei que não é uma boa pratica acessar direto o banco. Mas para essa aplicação tive que usar esse tipo de conexão ao invés de webservice.  Quando utilizei o try..catch consegui visualizar as mensagens.   A função IIF só existe a partir da versão 2012 do Sql server, o cliente está usando a versão 2008.

Comment: Seixas ainda bem que resolveste os problemas :)